# Am I using the constructor __init__ wrong?

Tags: class, python-3.x, constructor, initialization, pygame

I have a class that attempts to create an instance which is then defined as a sprite, but which also permits this instance to have other variables (this is a follow up on my progress on an atari breakout game for which I asked another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954224/how-do-i-create-many-precise-instances-of-a-class-to-access-their-attributes-t).)

> *Just a side note (probably not explained very well, sorry): I originally had all my attributes annexed to a 'brick' attribute:*
>
> `self.brick = pygame.sprite.Sprite() # the .brick is now a sprite`
>
> *because I thought it would be impossible to give a sprite user invented attributes such as* `self.brick.hardness` *so I did this instead:*
>
> `self.hardness = 1 # the object has another attribute not interfering with the sprite`
>
> *This created some conflicts with my sprite collision engine (long story short; the* `.brick` *attribute could not call the method* `blockType` *since it is not an instance of that class), so I just decided to make the actual instance a sprite, and this might be causing some conflicts with its ulterior attributes.*

The sprite is created through the __init_ constructor, and the other attributes are only added when the appropriate method is called.

```
class Block:        
    def __init__ (self):
        self = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def blockType (self, hardness):
        self.hardness = hardness
        if self.hardness == 1:
            self.image.fill (RED)

block = Block () # These parenthesis might be wrong here
block.blockType (1)
```

Now this issue might be due to inheritance once again, but when I create the instance, everything is fine. However when I attempt to call the method, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Block' object has no attribute 'image'
```

I think this is very strange since the object should possess an image attribute after having being created by just running the constructor method (if I don't call the method I am actually perfectly capable of drawing these sprites on screen so they do technically exist). I've tried making my way around this but at this point I just have absolutely no clue as to what is wrong.

If you need any more information, let me know and I will update.

Comment: I may have missed it in your question, but why don't you inherit your `Block` from `pygame.sprite.Sprite()`?

Comment: Your class `Block` doesn't inherit from `pygame.sprite.Sprite`, so why call the `Sprite.__init__` method here?

Comment: In your previous question you used the line `pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self.brick)`. That's not needed either, as using `Sprite()` to create the `self.brick` object *already called that method*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wow you're right. For some reason that's how my teacher taught it to is and that's how I always did it without questioning it. Thanks for pointing that out. Also, relating to your first comment, for some reason I thought that the `Sprite ()` method could be called anywhere since it was part of pygame but I guess class syntax always forces you to inherit other class properties before calling them right?

Comment: @AndresStadelmann: I think you misunderstood something then; when *inheriting* you (may) want to call the original `__init__` method on the base class. But you are not inheriting here; `Block` is not a `Sprite`, it only *contains* a sprite (`has-a` vs. `is-a` relationship).

Comment: @MartijnPieters At the time I had no idea what classes even were! My first version of this game was really messy. I can't believe it even worked without me implementing my own classes, so now I'm learning!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Isn't the `__init__` done through calling on the parent class with `super().__init__()`?

Comment: @AndresStadelmann: that's the better approach, but not the only one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using this code

```
class Block:        
    def __init__ (self):
        self = pygame.sprite.Sprite() # don't overwrite self here
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

you overwrite `self` (which is a reference to the newly created `Block` instance) with a new instance of `Sprite`; and that instance will get deleted sooner or later since you don't keep a reference of it.

I guess your intent was to subclass `Sprite` (which is quite common when using pygame), so you have to use:

```
class Block(Sprite):        
    def __init__ (self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Now `Block` is a subclass of `Sprite` and has the `image` and `rect` attributes.

Comment: Wow! Ok that makes much more sense now. I used to write `class Block (pygame.sprite.Sprite)` to try to inherit it and it would never work, but yes this is exactly what I needed, thank you very much!